# Ошибка при внедрении авторизации на сайте: Error POST 404 (OK)

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex, vue-router

Не могу понять, как решить проблему с POST-запросом.
Пытаюсь реализовать авторизацию на сайте (через Vuejs, vuex, vue-router, axios).
Я буду очень рад, если вы дадите несколько советов.
Я искал информацию на форумах, но ситуации описанные в других местах не подходят для моего случая. Почему 404 (ОК)? Если нормально, то почему 404? Это значит, что сервер получил мои данные, но не может сравнить правильны ли данные или нет?

У меня есть следующие компоненты/страницы:

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
      <div id="nav">
      <router-link to="/">Home page</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/login">Login</router-link>
      <span v-if="isLoggedIn"> | <a @click="logout">Logout</a></span>
    </div>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  computed : {
      isLoggedIn : function(){ return this.$store.getters.isLoggedIn}
    },
  methods: {
    logout: function () {
      this.$store.dispatch('logout')
      .then(() => {
        this.$router.push('/login')
      })
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    this.http.interceptors.response.use(function (err) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        if (err.status === 401 && err.config && !err.config.__isRetryRequest) {
          this.$store.dispatch("logout")
          resolve()
        }
        throw err;
      });
    });
  },
}
</script>
```

LoginAnalytics.vue
Здесь пользователь должен ввести данные: мобильный и пароль, для авторизации

```
<template>
 <div>
   <form class="login" @submit.prevent="login">
     <h1>Sign in</h1>
     <label>Mobile</label>
     <input required v-model="mobile" type="tel" placeholder="mobile phone"/>
     <label>Password</label>
     <input required v-model="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
     <hr/>
     <button type="submit">Login</button>
   </form>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        mobile : "",
        password : ""
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login: function () {
        let login = this.mobile 
        let password = this.password
        this.$store.dispatch('login', { login, password })
       .then(() => this.$router.push('/secure'))
       .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Vuex store.
Здесь я создаю axios post запрос для обращения к серверу.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_BASE_URL, TEMPORARY_TOKEN } from '../config';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state:{
    trainings: [],
    incomings: [],
    sources: [],
    avgShedule: [],
    metro: [],
    conversion: [],
    avgIncome: [],
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token') || '',
    user : {},
  },
  mutations:{
    auth_request(state){
      state.status = 'loading'
    },
    auth_success(state, token, user){
      state.status = 'success'
      state.token = token
      state.user = user
    },
    auth_error(state){
      state.status = 'error'
    },
    logout(state){
      state.status = ''
      state.token = ''
    },
  },
  getters:{
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    authStatus: state => state.status,
  },
  actions:{
    login({commit}, user){
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('auth_request')
        axios({
        url: `${API_BASE_URL}/analytics.auth`,
        data: user,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        }
      })
        .then(resp => {
          const token = resp.data.token
          const user = resp.data.user
          localStorage.setItem('token', token)
          axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
          commit('auth_success', token, user)
          resolve(resp)
        })
        .catch(err => {
          commit('auth_error')
          localStorage.removeItem('token')
          reject(err)
        })
      })
    },

    logout({commit}){
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      commit('logout')
      localStorage.removeItem('token')
      delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
      resolve()
    })
    }
  }
},
)
```

router.
Здесь все ссылки для переключения между страницами и компонентами.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import store from '@/store'
import Analytics from '@/pages/Analytics-test.vue'
import LoginAnalytics from '@/components/LoginAnalytics.vue'
import HomeAnalytics from '@/components/HomeAnalytics.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

let router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeAnalytics
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: LoginAnalytics
    },
    {
      path: '/secure',
      name: 'secure',
      component: Analytics,
      meta: { 
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      next()
      return
    }
    next('/login') 
  } else {
    next() 
  }
})


export default router
```

А также:  main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router';
import store from './store'
import axios from 'axios'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
if (token) {
  Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
}

new Vue({
  store,
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Каждый раз, когда я ввожу корректные данные для авторизации, у меня в консоли возникает следующая ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас есть свагер? Посмотрите параметры успешного запроса в свагере и те, что вы отправляете через свой код. Где-то что-то не правильно указали в запросе на бэк

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выяснил в чем проблема была.
Я опечатался в url API.
У меня стояло обращение к:

```
${API_BASE_URL}/analytics.auth
```

А надо было указать:

```
${API_BASE_URL}/account.auth.
```

Замылился глаз, что не видел проблемы.